# How to implement form authentication with MVC 5 and azure autoscalling

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, autoscaling

I have developed an application in MVC 5 which has form authentication. Now I am using azure autoscalling on the application. Form authentication is working fine when I use single instance but when I use autoscalling, form authentication stops working (user is not getting authenticated). I tried to give same machine key on all the instances but no success.

Any idea what changes I need to do in order to make form authentication working with azure autoscalling?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you must be using SQL server for the membership features. If Yes , then did you scale the SQL database too.

Also Have you added the application insight or some kind of logging in your application.

can you check the logs that which DB or source you are using to authenticate? Also if you find the source , can you run the query if your user is available in the DB or not?